# Managing users in a private TRAC

Tags: trac

Are there plugins for trac that enable cookie based authentication instead of http authentication, and allow keeping the site private for unknown users?

We want to allow customers outside the office to log in, add and look at the tickets on their projects, but not the projects for our other clients. Non techie users are always confused by a http login box rather than a form that asks for a username and password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from its home page:

The [Account Manager plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) offers several features for managing user accounts:

- allow users to register new accounts
- login via an HTML form instead of using HTTP authentication
- allow existing users to change their passwords or delete their accounts

Comment: Yes. We used it several months with LDAP integration and no problems arised.

Answer (score 0):

I second antispam on the Account Manager plugin. Also, if your trac needs to be web facing, you may be interested in the auth required plugin. Just be aware that it hasn't been upgraded for 0.11 and I suspect that there are some minor compatibility problems. It does do the job though.